# Python rookie question on some unusual syntax

Tags: python, list

I am reading thru some pygame examples and learning python, I thought I was doing well until I came upon this line of code in aliens.py example:

```
class Alien(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    """An alien space ship. That slowly moves down the screen."""

    speed = 13
    animcycle = 12
    images: List[pg.Surface] = []
```

I don't understand the use of a colon (:) as in,

```
imgaes:
```

And even what comes after colon,

```
List[pg.Surface]
```

is puzzling too, any hints or links to read up on would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: Thanks Rabbid76! It is pretty hard to do a web search for ":" so I appreciate the help : )